# Trying to create a lambda for filtering dates in linq to entities with additional complete check

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

Not long ago I posted the question [Trying to create a morethan, equal or greaterthan dynamic filter for dates in linq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57072538/trying-to-create-a-morethan-equal-or-greaterthan-dynamic-filter-for-dates-in-li) which helped a lot but I am trying to add an additional check at the moment so the lambda looks like this now

```
(left, right, equality, isCompleteCheck) => IsCompleteCheck == false | left equality right && IsCompleteCheck == true
```

I wrote this code:

```
    public static IQueryable<TSource> FilterCompleteDateComparison<TSource>(
        this IQueryable<TSource> source,
        Expression<Func<TSource, DateTime?>> left,
        DateTime? right,
        string equality,
        Expression<Func<TSource, bool>> isCompleteCheck)
    {
        //                                                                        CombinedExpression 
        //                                                FirstExpression        Comparison Expression     SecondExpression
        // (left, right, equality, isCompleteCheck) => IsCompleteCheck == false | left equality right && IsCompleteCheck == true

        if (right == null || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(equality))
            return source;

        Expression IsCompleteCheckExpression = isCompleteCheck.Body;
        BinaryExpression FirstExpression = Expression.Equal(IsCompleteCheckExpression, Expression.Constant(false, typeof(bool)));

        Expression LeftExpression = left.Body;
        Expression RightParameter = Expression.Constant(right, typeof(DateTime?));

        BinaryExpression ComparisonExpression = null;
        switch (equality)
        {
            case "lessthan":
                ComparisonExpression = Expression.LessThan(LeftExpression, RightParameter);
                break;
            case "equal":
                ComparisonExpression = Expression.Equal(LeftExpression, RightParameter);
                break;
            case "morethan":
                ComparisonExpression = Expression.GreaterThan(LeftExpression, RightParameter);
                break;
            default:
                throw new Exception(String.Format("Equality {0} not recognised.", equality));
        }

        BinaryExpression SecondExpression = Expression.Equal(IsCompleteCheckExpression, Expression.Constant(true, typeof(bool)));
        BinaryExpression CombinedExpression = Expression.Or(FirstExpression, Expression.And(ComparisonExpression, SecondExpression));

        return source.Where(Expression.Lambda<Func<TSource, bool>>(CombinedExpression, left.Parameters));
    }
```

which can be called by

```
BaseQuery.FilterCompleteDateComparison<SessionModel>(x => x.StartDate, DateValidated.Date, dateEquality, y => y.IsComplete);
```

but how do I supply the `IsCompleteCheckExpression` parameters to the lambda? I have tried to simply concat the `IsCompleteCheckExpression` parameters onto the `leftexpression` parameters and supply that to the lambda, but the error says that there is too many properties.

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Book recommendations are out of scope, but you should probably look out for resources generally about Abstract Syntax Trees (AST) and their transformations. If you understand the concept, the C# Expressions are not so difficult anymore.

Comment: Yes, you are right I shall remove it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use an `ExpressionVisitor` that can change the lambda parameter in `isCompleteCheck` to be the one in `left` so it is used for both lambda evaluations. This is often named `Replace`:

```
public static class ExpressionExt {
    /// <summary>
    /// Replaces an Expression (reference Equals) with another Expression
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="orig">The original Expression.</param>
    /// <param name="from">The from Expression.</param>
    /// <param name="to">The to Expression.</param>
    /// <returns>Expression with all occurrences of from replaced with to</returns>
    public static Expression Replace(this Expression orig, Expression from, Expression to) => new ReplaceVisitor(from, to).Visit(orig);
}

/// <summary>
/// ExpressionVisitor to replace an Expression (that is Equals) with another Expression.
/// </summary>
public class ReplaceVisitor : ExpressionVisitor {
    readonly Expression from;
    readonly Expression to;

    public ReplaceVisitor(Expression from, Expression to) {
        this.from = from;
        this.to = to;
    }

    public override Expression Visit(Expression node) => node == from ? to : base.Visit(node);
}
```

Given this, the change to your method is straightforward. I also simplified your test logic (my general rules say never test against boolean and be DRY, so `t1 == false || t2 && t1 == true` should be `!t1 || t2`). I also used a `Dictionary` instead of `switch` to make a more succinct/DRY and easily expandable comparison expression.

```
static Dictionary<string, Func<Expression, Expression, BinaryExpression>> ComparisonOps = new Dictionary<string, Func<Expression, Expression, BinaryExpression>> {
    { "lessthan", Expression.LessThan },
    { "equal", Expression.Equal },
    { "morethan", Expression.GreaterThan },
};

public static IQueryable<TSource> FilterCompleteDateComparison<TSource>(
      this IQueryable<TSource> source,
      Expression<Func<TSource, DateTime?>> left,
      DateTime? right,
      string equality,
      Expression<Func<TSource, bool>> isCompleteCheck) {
    //                                                            CombinedExpression 
    //                                                      FirstExpression    Comparison Expression
    // (left, right, equality, isCompleteCheck) => s => !IsCompleteCheck(s) || left(s) equality right

    if (right == null || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(equality))
        return source;

    var IsCompleteCheckExpression = isCompleteCheck.Body.Replace(isCompleteCheck.Parameters[0], left.Parameters[0]);
    var FirstExpression = Expression.Not(IsCompleteCheckExpression);

    var LeftExpression = left.Body;
    var RightParameter = Expression.Constant(right, typeof(DateTime?));

    if (!ComparisonOps.TryGetValue(equality, out var op))
            throw new Exception(String.Format("Equality {0} not recognised.", equality));

    var ComparisonExpression = op(LeftExpression, RightParameter);
    var CombinedExpression = Expression.Or(FirstExpression, ComparisonExpression);

    return source.Where(Expression.Lambda<Func<TSource, bool>>(CombinedExpression, left.Parameters));
}
```